# Plot a 1D array of varying column size arrays in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given that, I have arrays of x & y, I am able to plot easy the points, like so:

```
a = np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2)

plt.scatter(a.T[0], a.T[1])
plt.xlabel("Interval")
plt.ylabel("Value")
plt.show()
```

[image]

But currently, I have a list of lists with varying size, like so:

```
a = [
    [0, 1, 3],
    [4, 2],
    [1, 4, 7, 2],
    [2],
    [3, 4, 5, 6]
]

plt.scatter(a, list(range(len(a))))
plt.xlabel("Interval")
plt.ylabel("Value")
plt.show()
```

But, that gives an error: setting an array element with a sequence which surely will do when the dimensions aren't fixed and the sizes are not equal( (dimen) x != (dimen) y), but I am looking at getting something like that:

[image]

How can I obtain that kind of plot?

Comment: What is the reason to store lists of different lengths in a numpy array? Numpy is optimized for homogeneous arrays. What do you try to achieve by using numpy in this case?

Comment: @Mr.T I know, I used numpy arrays for homogeneous answers for the upper that I've used :p. I am trying to plot the most powerful frequency bins, and I'm using just bare lists for that...

Comment: @Bazingaa I think Meta is a better place than a random question to ask this.

Comment: @DomainFlag Mhm. Still don't understand what the advantage of a numpy array over a list of lists is, but ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost close. You can just use a **single for loop** to plot individual lists as following. `lst` will be one sublist at a time and 
`[i]*len(lst)` will generate the number of x-datapoints for that sublist.

```
for i, lst in enumerate(a):
    plt.scatter([i]*len(lst), lst,  color='r')
plt.xlabel("Interval")
plt.ylabel("Value")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could create the data to be plotted manually:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([
    [0, 1, 3],
    [4, 2],
    [1, 4, 7, 2],
    [2],
    [3, 4, 5, 6]

])

data = np.array([[x, y] for x, ys in enumerate(a) for y in ys])

plt.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], c='red')
plt.xlabel("Interval")
plt.ylabel("Value")
plt.show()
```

**Output**
[image]